# To Draw a Bar Chart with multiple data set

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

Survey is conducted with different gender
Age is in x-axis and number of people is in y axis
Age should be from 1-100

Ages of male ['28', '13', '17', '34', '37', '36', '35', '25', '32', '31', '26', '30', '29', '18', '27', '33']

Number of Male ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '5']

Ages of female ['28', '29', '27', '25', '30', '24']

Number of female ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '4']

Ages of others ['26', '25', '32', '31', '37', '33']

number of others ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2']

I tried below code

```
  const data = {
    labels:agesArr,
    datasets:[
      {
        label:'number of males',
        data:numberMale,
        backgroundColor:'aqua',
        borderColor:'black',
        border:1
      },
      {
        label:'number of females',
        data:numberFemale,
        backgroundColor:'yellow',
        borderColor:'black',
        border:1
      },
      {
        label:'number of others',
        data:numberOthers,
        backgroundColor:'red',
        borderColor:'black',
        border:1
      },
    ]
  }
  const options ={
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Chart Showing Number of people who took part in survey',
      },
    },
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      x: {
        display:true,
        text:'Age',
        stacked: false,
      },
      y: {
        display:true,
        text:'Number',
        stacked: false,
      },
    },
  };

    return (
        <>
            <Bar
            data={data}
            options={options}
            />
        </>
  )
```

ageArray is array of 1 to 100
This code did not give me desirable output
It will always give start from 1 without ploting different values.